# Why does printf() not print anything before sleep()?

Tags: c, stdout, buffering

I'm just learning C with Kernighan and Ritchie's book; I'm in the basics of the fourth chapter ("Functions and Program Structure"). The other day I became curious about the `sleep()` function, so tried to use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf(" I like cows.");
  sleep(5);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is the output of the program, it looks like it does the `sleep()` first and then the `printf()`, in other words, it waits five seconds and then prints the string. So I thought, maybe the program gets to `sleep()` so fast that it doesn't let `printf()` have his work done like I want, that is print the string and then sleep.

How can I show the string and then put the program to sleep?
The compiler is GCC 3.3.5 (propolice) in OpenBSD 4.3.

Answer (score 52):

`printf()` writes to `stdout` (the default output stream) which is usually line buffered.  The buffer isn't flushed by the time `sleep` is called so nothing is displayed, when the program exits all streams are automatically flushed which is why it prints right before exiting.  Printing a newline will usually cause the stream to be flushed, alternatively you could use the `fflush` function:

```
int main(void)
{
  printf(" I like cows.\n");
  sleep(5);
  return 0;
}
```

or:

```
int main(void)
{
  printf(" I like cows.");
  fflush(stdout);
  sleep(5);
  return 0;
}
```

If you are printing to a stream that is not line buffered, as may be the case if `stdout` is redirected or you are writing to a file, simply printing a newline probably won't work.  In such cases you should use `fflush` if you want the data written immediately.

Comment: The reason adding a \n to the string works is that printf to the console is line buffered.  However, if you redirect it to to a file it might not be enough because it uses a different buffering scheme.

Comment: Interesting question then is, how can you tell which buffering mode is your current file pointer using?

Comment: @Paul, right, that is why I said it will *usually* cause the stream to be flushed but I'll go ahead and clarify.

Comment: @Vinko, there is no standard function that will tell you what the buffering mode for a stream is but many implementations have their own functions (glibc has __flbf and __fbufsize for example).

Comment: @RobertGamble, well, I had learnt that `fflush (stdout)` is Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is that printf (and anything else that uses the stdio library to write to stdout (standard output)) is buffered - line buffered if it goes to the console, and size buffered if it goes to a file.  If you do a `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`, it will do what you want.  You could try just adding a newline ('\n') to your string, and that would do the right thing as long as you don't redirect standard output to a file.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think `stderr` isn't buffered, which can cause confusion because you might see output you made to `stderr` before output you previously made to `stdout`.

Comment: printf isn't buffered, the stream that it is writing to is.

Comment: stderr is usually unbuffered (although it may be line buffered).

Comment: why the newline('\n') does the job?

Comment: @johngonidelis because as I said before, it's line buffered. When it sees the end of a line, it flushes the buffer.

Answer (score 6):

Buffering means that all the output is stored in a place (called buffer) and is output after a certain amount of data is present in it. This is done for efficiency reasons.

Some (most?) implementations clear the buffer after a newline when writing to the console, so you can also try

```
printf(" I like cows.\n");
```

instead of the call to fflush()

Answer (score 1):

I implemented time encounter as following;

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 60; i++) {
    printf("%02d", i);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    printf("\b\b");
}
```