# Print characters with some delay using sleep()

Tags: c, sleep

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{   int n=3;
    while(n>0)
    {   printf("P");
        n--;
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With this code 3 P's are appearing at the same time after 3 seconds. But I want it to appear one by one with 1 second time interval. How should I modify it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does sleep() execute before my printf(), the opposite order of my code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338273/why-does-sleep-execute-before-my-printf-the-opposite-order-of-my-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the buffer is not flushed by `printf`. To do so, you can either print '\n' after your P :
`printf("P\n");`

Either call fflush on stdout :

```
printf("P");
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this one :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){  

 int n=3;
 sleep(1);

    while(n>0){   
        printf("P");
        n--;
        sleep(1);
      }
return 0;
}
```